# Can't edit text in input field getting error : beginbatchedit on inactive inputconnection

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am making an application using PhoneGap/Mobile jQuery on android. I am using phonegap version 2.3.0

I am able to edit some of the fields in form but when I start filling other it doesn't show the text inside fields.

I see many people get this problem but no one has got a solution yet

Here are some of the links where people get into the same problem

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_2_0_0_2_1_0_and_android_4_1_inputtext_text_not_taking_input_after_some_seconds
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/android_version_4_1_1

I don't have much experience with android, I am using HTML5 with phonegap

I use to setup application using the tutorial on their web http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

It create the application I name my application phonetest and my main java file contain this code.

```
/*
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
 */

package com.inam.phonetest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.cordova.*;


    public class phonetest extends DroidGap
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // testing asdfsd
            try
            {
                    String pName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
                    Log.w("myApp", "no network"+"/data/data/"+pName+"/databases/");
                    this.copy("cps.db","/data/data/"+pName+"/databases/");
                    //this.copy("0000000000000001.db","/data/data/"+pName+"/databases/file__0/");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            File database=getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("cps.db");

            if (!database.exists()) {
                // Database does not exist so copy it from assets here
                Log.w("Database", "Not Found");
            } else {
                Log.w("Database", "Found");
            }


            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              ////////////
            setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        }

        void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException 
        {

         File CheckDirectory;
         CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
         if (!CheckDirectory.exists())
         { 
          CheckDirectory.mkdir();
         }

            InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder+file);

            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len; while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);
            in.close(); out.close();

        }
    }
```

My HTML file has this script

```
<table><tr>
<td><input  name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" class="mytextfield"  style="height:35px; width:250px;" tabindex=""  value="" /></td>
      <td  ><font color="red">*</font>Home Phone Number </td>
      <td  ><input  name="phone_num" id="phone_num"  value=""  tabindex="" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="10" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show us your code, what have you tried to do?

Comment: I'm not much of an android developer. I follow the guide at phonegap to create android application and setup things as they said. I updated the question. Is there anything wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I was using `maxlength` and `max` in input fields and the field didn't restrict me from entering characters more than maxlength and max which somehow breaking any rule of something and it stop showing the words in field after that.